# Sql query to group_by items by sort - android

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I'm creating android app with lots of data user enters.

Now I need to display some data just like on the image below
[image]

I made first part of image, where all data is listed. Now I need to made some recapitulation where data is grouped by sort. If there are items with the same grade it needs to place them under the same row and count how many pieces of them are and also sum their masses and prices.

This is part of code where I'm displaying itemsList:

```
public class LogsRecapitulation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mainListView;
    private BaseAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_listview);
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewItem);

        //recieve RecepitID in displayLogs.activity
        final long forwardedId = (long) getIntent().getExtras().get(String.valueOf("recepitID"));
        List<Logs> logsList = new Select().from(Logs.class).where("Receipt = " + forwardedId).execute();


        listAdapter = new RecapitulationArrayAdapter(logsList);
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    private class RecapitulationArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Logs> logsList;

        public RecapitulationArrayAdapter(List<Logs> logsList) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(LogsRecapitulation.this);
            this.logsList = logsList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return logsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return logsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return logsList.get(position).getId();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logs_recapitulation, parent, false);
            }
            Logs log = logsList.get(position);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_log_sort)).setText(log.sort_id);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_log_class)).setText(log.grade);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_log_count)).setText(String.valueOf(logsList.size()));
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_logs_mass)).setText(String.format("%.2f m3", log.getM3()));

            if (log.receipt.priceType.equals("Na panju")) {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_log_price_default)).setText(String.valueOf(log.price.stumpPrice_kn));
            } else {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_log_price_default)).setText(String.valueOf(log.price.roadPrice_kn));
            }

            if (log.receipt.priceType.equals("Na panju")) {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_calculated_price)).setText(String.format("%.2f KN", log.price.stumpPrice_kn * log.getM3()));
            } else {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rec_calculated_price)).setText(String.format("%.2f KN", log.price.roadPrice_kn * log.getM3()));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

This upper code is not so important, but more important to me is to made this recapitulation and group items by sort and in each sort by grade.

**Question: How should I group items by sort and in each sort group them by grade (just like on image up)?** 
*Any help is welcome!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to your database schema, but the SQL query you might use to produce such a result where you group by "Sorts" is as follows:

```
SELECT Sort, Grade, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Pieces, ROUND(SUM(Mass), 2) AS 
TotalMass, Price, SUM(MassPrice) AS TotalMassPrice 
FROM LogsTable
GROUP BY Sort, Grade 
ORDER BY Sort DESC, Grade DESC;
```

producing a table like the following:

[image: Group table]

There's a problem with this query if the price for a given combination of Sort-Grade is not constant. In that case you might use `AVG(Price) AS AveragePrice` instead of using `Price`, as in the example.

The "grand total" row can be produced with a SQL query as such:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS TotalPieces, ROUND(SUM(Mass), 2) AS GrandTotalMass, AVG(Price) AS AveragePrice, SUM(MassPrice) AS GrandTotalMassPrice
FROM LogsTable;
```

producing a table like the following:

[image: Grand total table]

It's clear to me that the number actually being reported in the grand total row in your screenshot is not the average price, but some other metric.

You can easily convert these SQL queries to your query framework of choice. I haven't done so as you seem to demonstrate knowledge of how to do this already.